# Copy Azureblob from one container to another with metadata

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

How can I copy blob with its metadata from one container to another currently the copy of blob date is set to current date. How can i set the modified date of new blob from original blob.

```
 private void MoveBlobFromThisContainerToBackupContainer(CloudBlobContainer sourceContainer, string sourceDirectory, CloudBlobContainer backupContainer, string backupDirectory, bool isToAddSourceDirectory)
            {
                backupContainer.CreateIfNotExists();

                var sas = sourceContainer.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
                {
                    SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-15),
                    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                    Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write,
                });

                var blobs = sourceContainer.ListBlobs();
                if (sourceDirectory.Trim().Length > 0 && sourceDirectory.ToUpper() != "ALL")
                {
                    CloudBlobDirectory dir = sourceContainer.GetDirectoryReference(sourceDirectory);
                    blobs = dir.ListBlobs();
                }
                foreach (IListBlobItem sourceBlob in blobs)
                {
                    if (sourceBlob.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
                    {
                        CloudBlockBlob srcBlob = (CloudBlockBlob)sourceBlob;

                        string backupBlobName = srcBlob.Uri.Segments[srcBlob.Uri.Segments.Length - 1];
                        if (sourceDirectory.Length > 0 && isToAddSourceDirectory) backupBlobName = sourceDirectory + "\\" + backupBlobName;
                        if (backupDirectory.Trim().Length > 0) backupBlobName = backupDirectory + "\\" + backupBlobName;
                        lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                        lblStatus.Text = "Blob: " + backupBlobName;
                        CloudBlockBlob targetBlob = backupContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(backupBlobName);

                        if (targetBlob.Exists())
                        {
                            lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray;
                            lblStatus.Text = lblStatus.Text + " already Exists...not copied...";
                        }
                        else if (srcBlob.Properties.LastModified.Value.DateTime >= dateTimePicker1.Value )
                        {
                            var srcBlockBlobSasUri = string.Format("{0}{1}", srcBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri, sas);
                            targetBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(new Uri(srcBlockBlobSasUri));
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand your question is that you're looking for 2 things:

- **Preserve metadata when blob is copied from one account to another.**

This should be happening. Unless you specify metadata during copy operation, metadata of source blob should be copied over to the destination blob. From [`Copy Blob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894037.aspx) documentation:

> Optional. Specifies a user-defined name-value pair associated with the
>   blob. **If no name-value pairs are specified, the operation will copy
>   the metadata from the source blob or file to the destination blob.** If
>   one or more name-value pairs are specified, the destination blob is
>   created with the specified metadata, and metadata is not copied from
>   the source blob or file.

- **Preserve the modified date of source blob in destination blob.**

I don't think it is possible. Last modified date is a system property that gets updated as and when blob is created/updated. Since copy blob operation creates a new blob at destination, it will always have the last modified date as the time when it was created/last updated. You can't preserve that.

**UPDATE**

> can i set the date and time that the specified file was last written
>   to

Yes, you can. One way to accomplish this is by setting custom metadata on the target blob. The way it would work is you get the last modified date of the source blob and create a custom metadata entry (e.g. SourceBlobLastModified) and set its value to the last modified date of the source blob. Please note that if you want to copy the metadata of the source blob to the target blob, you must add each of the metadata item of the source blob as part of the copy operation along with this new metadata entry. Otherwise the target blob will only have one entry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ...can i set the date and time that the specified file was last written to..

Comment: Updated my answer. HTH.